# alineacion dos botones en un TD con Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

Estoy trabajando con Bootstrap y más precisamente ahora estoy intentando centrar estos dos botones en un TD pero se superponen al intentar alinearlos.

Aca el html:

```
              <td style="font-size:50%;">
                <div class="form-group row text-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                      <a href="{% url 'articulos:update' articulos.codigo %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button" aria-disabled="true">Editar</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                      <a href="{% url 'articulos:update' articulos.codigo %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button" aria-disabled="true">Eliminar</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </td>
```

Y Acá el como queda:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de que puede ser?

Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Por favor el código mínimo necesario para replicar tu escenario va como texto

Comment: @BetaM Gracias ahí lo puse como texto.

Answer (score 0):

Yo integro los botones de esta manera en un dataTable y se acomodan sin problema:

```html
<td  style="font-size:10x;">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info barcode" data-keyboard="false" data_backdrop="static" role="link" onclick="window.location='../escanearUsuario.php?numero_empleado=<?=md5($numero_empleado)?>'"  title="PROCESAR EMPLEADO"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode"></span></button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary time" data-keyboard="false" data_backdrop="static" role="link" onclick="window.location='..historialUsuario.php?numero_empleado=<?=md5($numero_empleado)?>'"  title="HISTORIAL DE USUARIO"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></button>

</td>
```

En mi aplicación donde utilizo este código  tengo una vista de 4 botones.

Comment: Gracias @Cesarin. Me gusta es layout, pero no me pude poner un href adentro.

Comment: por que no intentas colocar la etiqueta <a></a> para que puedas poner el link dentro del boton entre un <span></span>

Comment: tengo unos botones escritos tambien asi:   <a href="../solicitud_Baja.php" class="btn btn-secondary button"><img src="imagenes/iconos/acciones/misBajas.png" title="SOLICITUD DE BAJA" /></a><br>

Comment: Gracias @Cesarin me gusta mucho las formas de tus botones y sobre todo por son chiquitos, en cuanto tenga un poco más de tiempo voy a intentar reemplazrlos por los tuyos. Ahora tengo  otros issues con django jejeje. Al Final pude resolverlo siguiento la documentacion sobre botones de bootstrap. Muchas Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: @wwrandazzo De nada, de igual manera es ahí en donde me baso en la documentacion de bootstrap y algunos otros sitios o blogs.  Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo resolví de la siguiente según la nomenclatura de Button tags Bootstrap:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<td style="="font-size:30%;><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="{% url 'articulos:update' articulos.codigo %}" role="button">Editar</a><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="{% url 'articulos:delete' articulos.codigo %}" role="button">Borrar</a></td>
```